# video.jsによる動画の再生

Tags: javascript, jquery

video.jsを使用して、2分程度（150MB）のmp4を再生してみたのですが、動作が安定しません。（所々で止まる、インターネット接続は問題なし）

これは何が原因でしょうか。

詳しい方、ご教示頂けますと、幸いです。

Comment: 過去すべての質問について、回答へのフィードバックがありません。解決したなら解決済みとする、解決しないなら回答にコメントをする等、返答されることをオススメします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2分程度の動画が150MBですと、ストリーミング動画としてはかなり容量が大きく、一般的な回線で快適に再生することは難しいかもしれません。

例えばYouTubeの動画などでは、480pや720pあたりがよく再生されると思いますが、それぞれビットレートの目安は以下のようになります。([参考: Live encoder settings, bitrates and resolutions](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853702?hl=en))

- 480p: 500-2000Kbps
- 720p: 1500-4000Kbps

2分で150MBということは、秒間に直すと1.25MB、メガバイトをキロビットに直すと大体10000Kbps程度になりますので、YouTubeのよくあるレンジの2.5〜20倍の容量があることになります。

FFmpegやHandBrakeなどで事前にエンコードされることをお勧めします。